# Getting error "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

```
Cmd* GetCommand() {
            Cmd* command;
            char* cmdStr = getIn();
            command = parseL(cmdStr);
            return command;
   }

Cmd** parseL(char* str){
        Cmd** command;
        char* token;
        char str2[CMD_MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
        strcpy(str2, str);
        token = strtok(str2, DELI);
        command = ParC(token);
        return command;
}

Cmd* parC(char* cmdStr) {
    Cmd* command = calloc(1, sizeof(CmdCommand));
        if (cmdStr == NULL) {
            command->cmd = INVALID;
            return command;
        }
        else
            parse2C(cmdStr, command);
        return command;
    }
```

Hey, I'm new to C and got a problem in my code.

When I'm running this part of code I get an error:

```
assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.
```

for this line:

```
             command = parseL(cmdStr);
```

`command` is from type `Cmd*` and also the function `parseL` returns `Cmd*`, so I can't find out the problem.

Comment: Order of declarations matters in C. Define your functions before you use them.

Comment: you forgot to include the line number of your error!  Sure, a smart person could probably spot it, but it's best to include the entire error.  It will give you a line number.

Comment: Incidentally, if you need to call functions from each other, you can't define one before the other, so you'll want to split function declaration and definition (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration).  I don't think that's the case for you, but putting all the declarations atop will make the definition order unimportant.

Comment: You ignore another warnings . Never ignore the warning

Comment: "*the function parseL return Cmd**" from the code you show it does not.

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not add a cast** to suppress the (badly worded) warning.

Answer (score 1):

The moment the compiler sees

```
 command = parseL(cmdStr);
```

it does not know yet which type is returned by `parseL()`, as it is define later in the code.

For such cases <strike>the C Standard defines to</strike> many compilers assume `int` as return type.

As `command` is defined to be a pointer, the compiler chokes and issues the warning observed:

> ```
> error assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
> ```

To get around this issue

- either define the whole function
- or <strike>at least</strike> provide a prototype of the function

  ```
  Cmd** parseL(char*);
  ```

***before*** it is used.

---

As a side note:

You will run into the next error then as `Cmd**` is not the same as `Cmd*`.

Comment: Actually, the current standard, the previous standard, and the one prior to that all do _not_ assume `int`; they say 'error'.  Many compilers continue to allow the 'default `int`', but that isn't what any of the standards except the original C90 (C89) standard permits.  All other versions require the type to be known before the function is called.  You don't necessarily have to have a full prototype; you do have to have a declaration (or definition) for every function called before it is called.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thank you for taking care ... :}